# ActiveMQ JMS losing messages

Tags: java, applet, jms, message

I'm working on an application made of J2EE and Spring in backend and an applet in frontend.

After some user actions the backend send messages on an activeMQ topic to notify frontend to update IHM.

I'm facing a  problem where ActiveMQ Broker is invoked to send message, but the frontend doesn't receive all messages, the `onMessage()` method of the `MessageListener` is not invoked sometimes. The front receive some messages but not all, from the same type on the same topic.Its a random behavior.

My configuration is as below:
activemq.xml

```xml
<amq:broker useJmx="false" persistent="false">
    <amq:transportConnectors>
        <amq:transportConnector uri="tcp://0.0.0.0:18135" />
    </amq:transportConnectors>

</amq:broker>
```

broker-config.xml

```xml
<beans>

    <bean id="broker" class="org.apache.activemq.xbean.BrokerFactoryBean">
        <property name="config">
            <!-- ENV-ACTIVEMQ_XML -->
            <value>WEB-INF/config/jms/activemq.xml</value>
        </property>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

producer-config.xml

```xml
<beans>

    <!-- JMS ConnectionFactory to use -->
    <bean id="jmsFactory" class="org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory">
        <property name="brokerURL">
            <value>vm://localhost</value>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <!-- Spring JMS Template -->
    <bean id="jmsTemplate" class="org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate">
        <property name="connectionFactory">
            <!-- lets wrap in a pool to avoid creating a connection per send -->
            <bean class="org.apache.activemq.pool.PooledConnectionFactory">
                <property name="connectionFactory">
                    <ref local="jmsFactory" />
                </property>
            </bean>
        </property>

        <!-- true for TOPIC mode, false for QUEUE mode -->
        <property name="pubSubDomain">

                <value>true</value>

        </property>
    </bean>

    <!-- a sample POJO which uses a Spring JmsTemplate -->

    <bean id="producer" class="com.airfrance.rushtbeweb.applicationlayer.broker.AlertProducer">
        <property name="template">
            <ref bean="jmsTemplate"></ref>
        </property>
        <property name="subject">
            <value>ALERTES</value>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

In the client site, the connection is set as:

```
hostName = (String) Applet.getCtx().getAttribute(Constants.SERVER_HOSTNAME);
            //serverPort = (String)      Applet.getCtx().getAttribute(Constants.SERVER_PORT);
            serverPort = "18135";
            if (log.isInfoEnabled()){
            log.info("hostName :"+ hostName );
            log.info("serverPort :"+ serverPort );}


if (StringUtils.isNotEmpty(hostName)&& StringUtils.isNotEmpty(serverPort)) {
                connectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory("tcp://"+ hostName + ":" + serverPort);
                if (log.isInfoEnabled()){
                log.info("connectionFactory: "+ connectionFactory);}
                connection = (TopicConnection) connectionFactory.createConnection();
                if (log.isInfoEnabled()){
                log.info("connection : "+ connection ); }
                connection.setClientID(myId);
                createConsumer(connection);

                connection.start();

                // Permet une reconnexion du client avec une phase
                // d'initialisation en cas de problème de connexion.
                connection.setExceptionListener(new AbstractJMSExceptionListener(connectionFactory, connection) {
                            public void reinitialize() throws JMSException {
                                createConsumer(getExListenerConnection());
                            }
                        });

                while (isRunning) {
                    Thread.sleep(5000);
                }......
private void createConsumer(TopicConnection topicConnection)
            throws JMSException {
        if (log.isInfoEnabled()){
        log.info("STEP createConsumer");}
        // securise la reception de l'alerte
        // Vis a vis du broker le message est acquitté seulement si on passe
        // sur la methode acknowledge()
        TopicSession session = topicConnection.createTopicSession(false,Session.CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE);
        Topic topic = session.createTopic(SUBJECT);
        TopicSubscriber subscriber = session.createSubscriber(topic);
        subscriber.setMessageListener(this);
    }
```

I've tried to make message persistent with KahaDB, and change the `createSubscriber` to `createDurableSubscriber`, with no result.

Comment: Can I make an up to this question!?